# Run shell script with Angular CLI commands from Java

Tags: java, angular, shell, angular-cli

I'm trying to run a shell script from Java (using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)). All commands in the script file seem to be running normally except the angular-cli (ng) commands.

My Java File:

```
System.out.println("Executing Script...");
final String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "test.sh"};
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String s;
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Script output: " + s);
}
process.destroy();
System.out.println("Script Executed.");
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/ && 
ng new newAngularProject &&
```

Outout:

```
Executing Script...
Script Executed.
```

No errors are thrown. All other commands work but for some reason, I'm unable to run ng commands. Also, I've tested the file w/o running it from Java - When I run the same script directly on the console, it works perfectly and all commands (including ng commands) work neatly. I'm running on MacOS in case you wanted to know.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Also print the error stream. You will get the error message, if it is there.

```
    final BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    while ((s = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("error: " + s);
    }
```

Also you can try to use absolute path of `ng` in your `test.sh` e.g. /home/my/install/node-vxxx/ng, since the process spawn by java to run your command might not get the environment variable you set in your .bashrc /.bash_aliases